# Best multivariate polynomial fit in Matlab, Mathematica or R

Tags: r, matlab, wolfram-mathematica, linear-regression

I have a dataset (x,y) where x is a n-dimensional vector and y is an m-dimensional vector. (m=3, n>2)
My goal is to find the best polynomial in x fitting the (x,y) dataset.

The dimension of x is pretty big (right now it is 25), and I don't want to enter manually all the possibilities (ie x1*x3*x5, x1*x4*x6, ...). I can use Matlab, Mathematica and R. How can I do this?

Also, I would be interested in hearing your suggestions about the following problem: how can I choose from the result the most relevant coefficients? (maybe x1*x2 is more relevant than x2*x3)

Thank you

Comment: What is "best polynomial"? Obviously, the (n-1)th order polynomial will fit the data perfectly, as it will pass through all the points. But it is also likely to overfit your data.

Comment: I'm looking for a polynom of degree 2 or 3. I am talking about linear regression here, sorry for not being clear in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not really about any of the analysis platforms, but rather instead how to properly do multivariate analysis. As such it should be augmented with a description of the subject area. There also needs to be appropriate consideration of the implicit multiple testing that is occurring and what sort of penalization should be performed to avoid inflation of the inferential statistics. Bottom line: You should read Frank Harrell's "Regression Modeling Strategies", where each of these sentences get expanded into a full-length chapter. (I also think the question is overly broad and should be closed or migrated to stats.stackexchange.) It is not ready for prime-time coding.

Comment: I think you're right, however I was looking for a function in the said programs. I'll ask it there then, and I'll try to find the book.

Comment: I think your overall strategy (as I read it currently) of throwing in 25 predictors in the form of polynomial terms is just wrong. Harrells' ols function can be used with rcs() terms to get the spline fits but he recommends thorough consideration of predictor correlation before regression analysis. He also recommends that your inferences be penalized. If you have 25 predictors in 2way combinations and polynomial fits your degrees of freedom will be in the hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to DWin's answer:

With respect to your polynomial, you can express that by linear regression on the van der Monde matrix, and then use multivariate linear regression. However, with many variates you'll probably find that you rather need to restrict the model than allow further degrees of freedom.

> Also, I would be interested in hearing your suggestions about the following problem: how can I choose from the result the most relevant coefficients? (maybe x1*x2 is more relevant than x2*x3)

This boils down to variable selection, which a notoriously hard problem. I think Efron named it as one of the big unsolved problems...